# Google API - C# - GmailService - Error "Unable to validate id_token"

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am having an error when I try to access my gmail messages, even though I pass the permission type, which allows access to the readMessages.
What I want to do and am having trouble doing:

- Access unread emails
- Send e-mails

Function I am calling:

[image: Method]

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: what is Email? are you sure its the current users email address?

Comment: it is an email yes, I can send an email already, but I can't access the messages (email), when I try it gives error, I will update the question to put what errors I am having.

Comment: I was following your tutorial and was able to send email and authenticate, but when I try to read the messages the above error occurs @DaImTo

Comment: Did you change the scopes after you authorized the user?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, it was the id_token stored in "Cookies" in the browser, thanks for the help, and I liked your tutorials very much @DaImTo

Comment: in the future you should post your code and not images of your code.  Happy i could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the id_token that was stored in the browser's "Cookies", so when I changed the scopes it gave an error because the id_token is still from the old scope.
Deleting the ids stored in "Cookies" solved the problem.

[image: Solution]